# How does one submit a job requesting a specific GPU in condor without a submission file?

Tags: hpc, condor

I want to do:

```
condor_submit -i request_cpus=8 request_gpus=1 -requirements="(CUDADeviceName!='Tesla K40m')"
```

but due to the spaces and commas, I cannot do this. I also tried:

```
condor_submit -i request_cpus=2 request_gpus=1 -requirements=(CUDADeviceName!=TeslaK40m)
```

but it failed.

It does work with a submission file e.g.

```
Request_gpus = 1
Request_cpus = 2
requirements = (CUDADeviceName != "Tesla K40m")
# requirements = (CUDADeviceName == "Quadro RTX 6000")
Queue
```

so please don't recommend that I already have that working. I want it in one line on the command line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
-requirements='(CUDADeviceName != "Tesla K40m")'
```